# Replacing multiple special characters in oracle

Tags: regex, oracle, special-characters, regexp-replace

I have a requirement in oracle to replace the special characters at **first and last position** of the column data.

**Requirement:** only `[][.,$'*&!%^{}-?]` and alphanumberic characters are allowed to stay in the address data and rest of the characters has to be replaced with space.I have tried in below way in different probabilities but its not working as expected. Please help me in resolving this.

```sql
SELECT emp_address,
       REGEXP_REPLACE(
         emp_address,
         '^[^[[][.,$'\*&!%^{}-?\]]]|[^[[][.,$'\*&!%^{}-?\]]]$'
       ) AS simplified_emp_address
FROM   table_name
```

Comment: `REGEXP_REPLACE(emp_address, '^[^][.,$''*&!%^{}?-]|[^][.,$''*&!%^{}?-]$', '')`? Or, if you mean to remove multiple chars, `'^[^][.,$''*&!%^{}?-]+|[^][.,$''*&!%^{}?-]+$'`?

Comment: Please add sample data to your question to make it more clear.

Comment: Do you mean that you only want to remove those specific 15 characters from the first/last position; or that you want to remove any special character (however you define that) *except* those 15? It's not clear what you mean by 'allowed'. Please edit the question to make it clearer, and include representative sample data and expected results for values that should and should not be modified.

Comment: hello @AlexPoole, only those 15 characters and alphanumeric are allowed in my address. Rest of the special characters has to be replaced by space. I have edited my question for better understanding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the [regular expression operators and metasymbols documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/sqlrf/Multilingual-Regular-Expression-Syntax.html#GUID-B03DEEAC-3F9E-4BFD-89D5-F481EA391D7C):

- Put `]` as the first character of the (negated) character group;
- `-` as the last; and
- Do not put `.` immediately after `[` or it can be matched as the start of a coalition element `[..]` if there is a second `.` later in the expression.

Also:

- Double up the single quote (to escape it, so it does not terminate the string literal); and
- Include the non-special characters `a-zA-Z0-9` in the capture group too otherwise they will be matched.

Which gives you the regular expression:

```sql
SELECT emp_address,
       REGEXP_REPLACE(
         emp_address,
         '^[^][,.$''\*&!%^{}?a-zA-Z0-9-]|[^][,.$''\*&!%^{}?a-zA-Z0-9-]$'
       ) AS simplified_emp_address
FROM   table_name
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name (emp_address) AS
SELECT '"test1"' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '$test2$' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '[test3]' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'test4' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '|test5|' FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

> | EMP_ADDRESS | SIMPLIFIED_EMP_ADDRESS |
> | --- | --- |
> | "test1" | test1 |
> | $test2$ | $test2$ |
> | [test3] | [test3] |
> | test4 | test4 |
> | |test5| | test5 |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=6944d06d36de0cf64ac94f6a0f23d150)*

Answer (score 0):

You do not need regular expressions, because they will have cumbersome escape sequences. Use substrings and `translate` function:

> ```
> with a as (
>   select
>     'some [data ]' as val
>   from dual
>   union all
>   select '{test $' from dual
>   union all
>   select 'clean $%&* value' from dual
>   union all
>   select 's' from dual
> )
> select
>   translate(substr(val, 1, 1), q'{ [][.,$'*&!%^{}-?]}', ' ')
>   || substr(val, 2, lengthc(val) - 2)
>   || case
>        when lengthc(val) > 1
>        then translate(substr(val, -1), q'{ [][.,$'*&!%^{}-?]}', ' ')
>      end
>   as value_replaced
> from a
> ```
>
> ```
> | VALUE_REPLACED   |
> | :--------------- |
> | some [data       |
> | test             |
> | clean $%&* value |
> | s                |
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=9d2c170af3cf6eee56334f7781048503)*

Comment: @chan - this removes those 15 characters, rather than retaining just those; partly what prompted my comment asking for clarification. With MTO's sample data [it gets a very different result](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=caa6b594b4a192e863deca7a288f1482).

Comment: @AlexPoole Yes, you are right. I misunderstood "only those characters are allowed" as only those characters are possible candidates for replacement. After the edit of the question this answer became at least irrelevant.

Comment: It was unclear... My comment was in response to a now-deleted one from chan saying this worked too, which was also confusing. Good approach for what you thought the question was though *8-)

Comment: @AlexPoole. It worked for me. Only tweak I did is to replace the non matching characters to space/Blank. I am sorry if my question was not clear enough. No the other answer didnt give me the accurate answer.